# ArrayList Java Addition

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

Please help me to why am getting strange output for this Below Code.....
why am getting null for the getName().

**Output :**

List Check :null:1

```
public class ListTest
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List<Movie> lst = new java.util.ArrayList<Movie>();
    lst.add(new Movie("move1", "genre1"));
    System.out.println("List Check :" + lst.get(0).getName() + ":"
                    + lst.size());
}
}

class Movie
{
private String name;
private String genre;

public Movie(String name, String genre)
{
    name = this.name;
    genre = this.genre;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGenre()
{
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre)
{
    this.genre = genre;
}

}
```

Comment: Try `this.name = name` instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
public Movie(String name, String genre)
{
    name = this.name;
    genre = this.genre;
}
```

should be

```
public Movie(String name, String genre)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.genre = genre;
}
```

like in the setters.

Comment: @adenoyelle no, except you want to overwrite the passed parameters with the ones from the object (which are null). You know about name shadowing?

Answer (score 1):

The local variables, `name` and `genre` are being assigned to the global variable names of the same name in the constructor of `Movie`. The default value of `Object` types is `null` so these variables remain unassigned. The corrected constructor should appear as

```
public Movie(String name, String genre) {
   this.name = name;
   this.genre = genre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning parameters using this.name should be other way around

```
public Movie(String name, String genre)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.genre = genre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your constructor is wrong, it should be

```
public Movie(String name, String genre)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.genre = genre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reimeus has it right.

The "this" refers to the class itself, so "this.genre" would refer to the class variable "genre".

Switch them around to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you write name = this.name, you are assigning the value of the this.name to name. So in your case, this.name holds null when initialised and you are assigning it to name.

It is a good practice to use the getters and setters that you have written in your bean. 
you can set it like `setName(name)` instead of writing `this.name=name`. Both eventually perform the same action though.

Comment: If this is a good practice I don't like it. In code where this is done you have to check where the setter is called and where the object is accessed directly. This regularly makes me mad. So in my opinion it is a good practice to call setters and getters only from outside of the object.